# java object getClass() method returns null

Tags: java, serialization, reflection

My understanding is if a java object xx is not null there must be corresponding `Class` object for that object that can get using `getClass()` method, but some time this method returns `null` at run time that is very strange.

Example :

The object (oldFact) is serializble object that is referenced in `ExternalFactUpdateDroolsEvent` class as blew, this call get serialized and deserilized in it's excution process, means first many objects of type `ExternalFactUpdateDroolsEvent` get serialized and latter get desterilized before execution, in this process some time oldFact object returns `null` `Class` object that is causing problem.

My question is if an object is not `null` how `getClass()` method returns `null`? Is this some thing related to deserilized object that in not properly initializing / instantiating or some thing else, these object might be getting serialized from different JVM and then getting executed on one JVM.

```
public class ExternalFactUpdateDroolsEvent implements DroolsEvent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8225631607832350264L;

    private Object oldFact;

    public ExternalFactUpdateDroolsEvent(Object oldFact) {
        this.oldFact = oldFact;
        this.updatedFact = updatedFact;
    }

    public void executeAction(StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession) {
        // some time getClass() returns null that is strange  
        Class factClass = oldFact.getClass();

        ........................
    }

    ......................
}
```

Adding more content:

I am sure oldFact is not null because no nullPointer exception on oldFact.getClass(); call, 
the Class objecr factClass is being passed to other mentod where null is being asserted that's 
where we exception is throwing. See the code and exception as below.
I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it returns null?

Comment: `.getClass()` can't return `null`.

Comment: Box(Cast) the oldFact to ExternalFactUpdateDroolsEvent or whatever class it belongs to

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace? Maybe you have a bug after `Class factClass...`?

Answer (score 10):

Let me guess that you receive a NullPointerException in this line:

```
Class factClass = oldFact.getClass();
```

Due to the fact, that getClass() can't return null (**EDIT:** Even if getClass() would return null, that wouldn't cause a NullPointerException), oldFact must be the one which is null.

Comment: Besides, even *if* *getClass()* returned *null* this would not cause a problem in the code you provided.

Comment: Sorry, was actually referring to the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

the whole point is, oldfact is null because when you send a handle in `ExternalFactUpdateDroolsEvent` you send a null pointer so oldfact remains a null object, so when you type `oldfact.getclass()` there is nothing to get

edit--

or this happens if you call method `executeaction` before calling `ExternalFactUpdateDroolsEvent`

Answer (score 0):

Altough a bit late to the party, I just saw this searching for the same answers. Shouldn't `private Object oldFact;` be initialized as a new Object?

```
private Object oldFact;
```

to:

```
private Object oldFact = new Object();
```

Comment: It's a good practice to add your code snippets inside code sample tag.